# Enlarge row-height dynamically with pictures size

Tags: tables, graphics, multicolumn, multirow, size

I am building a table in LaTex that contains a column of pictures. I would like the size of the rows related to those pictures to increase their height such that the picture stays inside its cell. I tried the `\\[2cm]` solution, but then the text in the cells of the same rows is not centered anymore. An example to be clearer:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c c c|c c c}

    \multirow{ 2}{*}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{mesh}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{dofs}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{levels}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{iterations}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\textbf{Conv Rate}}  \\ \cline{5-10}
    & & & & \footnotesize{SGMG} & \footnotesize{NMG} & \footnotesize{AMG} & \footnotesize{SGMG}  & \footnotesize{NMG} & \footnotesize{AMG}\\\hline
    
    \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{1D}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale = .2]{path1}& \multirow{ 2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \hline
    
 \multirow{8}{*}{\textbf{2D}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale = .1]{path2}& \multirow{2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\[2cm] \cline{2-10}
    
    & \multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh22} &  \multirow{2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    &  & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
    
     &\multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh23}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{100k}& 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
    
    & \multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh24}&   \multirow{2}{*}{100k}& 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \hline
    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to just put your picture and see all the other text centered in the other cells ?

Comment: You should consider the package `tabularray`.

Comment: I have problems when using it (see comment below the following answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a combination of `vspan=even` from the `tabularray` package and `valign=c` from `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tblr}{vspan=even}
    \multirow{ 2}{*}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{mesh}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{dofs}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{levels}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{iterations}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\textbf{Conv Rate}}  \\ \cline{5-10}
    & & & & \footnotesize{SGMG} & \footnotesize{NMG} & \footnotesize{AMG} & \footnotesize{SGMG}  & \footnotesize{NMG} & \footnotesize{AMG}\\\hline
%    
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{1D}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=c]{example-image}}& \multirow{ 2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \hline
%    
 \multirow{8}{*}{\textbf{2D}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image}}& \multirow{2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
%    
    & \multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh22} &  \multirow{2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    &  & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
%    
     &\multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh23}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{100k}& 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
%    
    & \multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh24}&   \multirow{2}{*}{100k}& 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \hline    
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying this solution but some problems rise: I had to manually install tabularray, but now TeXStudio seems to recognize it. When I try the table, these errors are printed:

``LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'Ne' invalid for base form '\prop_item:Nn'. For immediate help type H <return>.``

``LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ce' invalid for base form '\tl_const:Nn'. For immediate help type H <return>.``


``LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'en' invalid for base form '\tl_if_eq:nnT'. For immediate help type H <return>.``

Comment: I think you should try to update thouroughly  your LaTeX distribution (moreover, the package `tabularray` is present in TeXLive, MikTeX and MacTex and, so, you should not have to install manually `tabularray`).

Comment: Ok, I had to install a new version of TeX Live. Now, Could you add something to centering the various fields ? horizontally centering. Like the task taht {c|c|c|c|c c c|c c c}
 of tabular does

Comment: Almost there, if I put ``\begin{tblr}{c|c|c|c|c c c| c c c}`` everything is centered, but I lose the vertical spacing. If I put both ``\begin{tblr}{c|c|c|c|c c c| c c c}{vspan=even}``, one of the two does not work. Any ideas to make them work togeter ?

Comment: I had to add the line ``\SetTblrInner{vspan=even}`` before ``being{tblr}``. Everything works fine, many thanks